# wp_redirect() not working and not redirecting to another page in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a form in admin panel. when i submit a form, it needs to redirect to another page. I have used

**"wp_redirect(get_site_url().'/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage_grill_submenu', 301);exit;"**

but, it is not redirecting to the desired page.I have searched a lot to fix this issue.

Does anyone know what could be wrong??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What action is your code running in? You need to redirect before headers are sent to the browser. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score -1):

If in case `wp_redirect` is not working, you can redirect to another page:

```
echo "<script>window.location.href = '".home_url()."/wp-login.php'";
echo "</script>";
```